# unit-testing / mocking a class which contains functionality which depends on itself

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

Take the below code:

```
public interface ISettingsManager
{
    SettingData GetSettingByIdentifierOrCreateIfDoesNotExist(Enum identifier);
    T GetSetting<T>(Enum identifier);

}

[IocComponent]
public class SettingsManager : ISettingsManager
{
    private readonly ISettingGetItemByIdentifierService _settingGetItemByIdentifierService;

    public SettingsManager(
        ISettingGetItemByIdentifierService settingGetItemByIdentifierService)
    {
        _settingGetItemByIdentifierService = settingGetItemByIdentifierService;
    }

    public SettingData GetSettingByIdentifierOrCreateIfDoesNotExist(Enum identifier)
    {
        SettingData setting = //GetSetting from database;
        return setting;
    }

    #region ISettingsManager Members


    public T GetSetting<T>(Enum identifier)
    {
        var setting = GetSettingByIdentifierOrCreateIfDoesNotExist(identifier);
        return (T)setting.Value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The `ISettingsManager` is created to retrieve settings for an application.  The main logic is done in `GetSettingByIdentifierOrCreateIfDoesNotExist`.  The logic is not shown in the example, but this should try to get the setting from the database.

The method `GetSetting` is a convenience method which basically retrieves the setting from the other method, and casts it to the required value as `setting.Value` is of type `object`.

I am trying to follow the Test-Driven-Development guidelines, and hence I assume a unit-test should be created for this method as well.   As it is, one cannot just mock the `GetSettingByIdentifierOrCreateIfDoesNotExist`, as it is in the same class.

Does it make sense to split this out in another class, so one can mock it?  Personally, I think that these two go together.  Any ideas how one would approach this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If you're following TDD, you should have written the tests `before` the actual code :)

Comment: I did create the tests, and they're not posted here :) I'm just thinking that it might be a bit of an over-kill, creating unit-tests for such simple methods, when it is just a 'convenience method'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need `GetSettingByIdentifierOrCreateIfDoesNotExist` declaration in your interface... Do you have special use cases where `GetSetting<T>` is not enough?

If I'm right and all you need is just `GetSetting<T>` method then you can go ahead and make `GetSettingByIdentifierOrCreateIfDoesNotExist` method private, thus you'll make it an implementation specific that doesn't need to be tested separately, you'll test it by testing `GetSetting<T>`.

If you do need `GetSettingByIdentifierOrCreateIfDoesNotExist` method, then I would go with a different approach: since `GetSetting<T>` is just an additional feature on top of `GetSettingByIdentifierOrCreateIfDoesNotExist`, you can remove it from `ISettingsManager` interface and rewrite as an extension method like this:

```
public interface ISettingsManager
{
    SettingData GetSettingByIdentifierOrCreateIfDoesNotExist(Enum identifier);
}

public static class SettingsManagerExtensions
{
    public static T GetSetting<T>(this ISettingsManager manager, Enum identifier)
    {
        var setting = manager.GetSettingByIdentifierOrCreateIfDoesNotExist(identifier);
        return (T)setting.Value;
    }
}
```